# Why is there a problem with my button movement?

Tags: button, move

I am writing a program, where I'd like to open a class by the press of a button. I have two buttons on a window, the first one works perfectly, but I can't seem to be able to move the second one (called "Teacher"). Here is the code. I am desperately looking for the solution. Thanks!

```
class MyHandler implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    System.exit(0);
     }
}
```

class MyFrame extends JFrame {

```
    private int size;
    private String font;

    MyFrame (String name){
        super (name);
        setBounds(500,500,600,400);
        setResizable(false);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //log in text
        JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Log in");
        lbl.setBounds(250, 60, 600, 50);

        size = 40;
        font = "Arial";
        lbl.setFont(new Font(name,Font.PLAIN,size));
        add(lbl);

        //adding button
        JButton btn = new JButton("Student");
        btn.setBounds(150, 260, 60, 40);
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                dispose();
                new Frame("StudentLogIn");
            }
        });
        add(btn);



        //adding second button
        JButton teach = new JButton("Teacher");
        teach.setBounds(100,260,60,40);
        teach.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                dispose();
                new FrameTeach("TeacherLogIn");
            }
        });
        add(teach);


        setVisible(true);



    }
}





public class StartingWindow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new MyFrame("Starting Window");

    }

}
```